# Puppet read file content and generate a hash

Tags: puppet

I have a file called fstab.txt which contains:

```
UUID=86861354-d783-4b9e-a871-e9fbbfc35c22   /mnt/d1 ext4    defaults    1   2
UUID=ffa788ba-0802-4305-ab59-2a34dda3a706   /mnt/d2 ext4    defaults    1   2
UUID=993eec37-9c6d-4ba6-9ed3-77f2d7652256   /mnt/d3 ext4    defaults    1   2
UUID=36817374-0d46-4d5b-ac9b-2229268b0978   /mnt/d4 ext4    defaults    1   2
```

I want to read the file and generate a hash as below:

```
hash = {
    "UUID=86861354-d783-4b9e-a871-e9fbbfc35c22" => "/mnt/d1",
    "UUID=ffa788ba-0802-4305-ab59-2a34dda3a706" => "/mnt/d2",
    "UUID=993eec37-9c6d-4ba6-9ed3-77f2d7652256" => "/mnt/d3",
    "UUID=36817374-0d46-4d5b-ac9b-2229268b0978" => "/mnt/d4",
}
```

Currently I am thinking this way:

```
$output = generate("/bin/cat fstab.txt")
```

And split out $output.

Some one could guide me a better way to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This can only work with `puppet apply`. If you use `puppet agent`, then the **master** will run the command and use its local fstab.

Comment: Ya i am using puppet agent and want to read that file /etc/fstab.

Comment: You need to create a [custom fact](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/facter/latest/custom_facts.html) for this.